# C++ coin purse program

Tags: c++, console-application

> Yes this is an assignment, not looking for answer just guidance.

Create a structure Coin and a class Purse. 
A coin has a name and monetary value.

Choose your way to implement a coin, but provide a way to check that two coins have equal names and monetary values.

A purse holds a collection of coins. Make a Purse constructor to construct an empty purse and the following methods of the class Purse:

A-  Add a number of instances of a coin to the purse. **Parameters:** the coin to add and how many of it.

B-  Count the number of coins in the purse that match a given coin. **Parameter:** the coin to match. Return value: the number of coins equal to the coin to match.

C-  Get the total value of the coins in the purse. Return the sum of all coin values.

D-  Count the number of coins in the purse. Return the number of coins.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

enum class coinType { penny = 1, nickel = 5, dime = 10, quarter = 25 };




struct Coin
{
string  name;
unsigned int value;
};

class Purse
{
public:
Purse(const std::vector<Coin>& Bank);

public:
void AddCoin(coinType type_coin, int num_coins);
int CountCoins(coinType type_coin) const;
int CoinValue() const;
int CountAllCoins() const;

private:
vector<int> coins;
};


int main()
{
vector< Coin > Bank{ { "Penny", 1 }, { "Nickel", 5 }, { "Dime", 10 }, { 
"Quarter", 25 } };

for (auto loop = 0; loop < Bank.size(); loop++)
{
    cout << "Coin: " << Bank[loop].name << ",\tvalue: " << Bank[loop].value 
<< '\n';
}
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is all I have so far. right track? suggestions? hints??

Comment: Do you have a specific question about something you're having trouble with? This isn't a code review site.

Comment: I am having trouble with the purse class, coming up with the constructor

Comment: Think of it in real world terms.  A purse is just basically a container that holds a collection of coins.  You have the container, now you need to add something to represent the collection.

Comment: So maybe something like this: public:
           Purse();             // Constructor
   bool    insert(Coin_type);  // Put a member in the purse
   bool    remove(Coin_type);  // remove a member from the purse
   int     size();            // number of members in purse
   void    clear();           // remove all members from purse
   bool    inPurse(Coin_type);   // is a member in the purse?
   int     howmany(Coin_type); // how many member in purse.

Answer (score 0):

You need a collection of coins as a property of Purse, so declare the private member and set it in the constructor by a parameter.

Comment: class Purse {

private:
   int       count;     // members in bag
   bag_type  data[20];  // data store up to 20 members

public:
           Purse();             // Constructor
   bool    insert(Purse_type);  // Put a member in the bag
   bool    remove(Purse_type);  // remove a member from the bag
   int     size();            // number of members in bag
   void    clear();           // remove all members from bag
   bool    inPurse(Purse_type);   // is a member in the bag?
   int     howmany(Purse_type); // how many member in bag.
};